# org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am using `org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod`. It is giving me *Null pointer exception*.

Following is my first class

```
package com;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        t.getName();
    }

    void getName() {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("com.test1");
            Object o = c.newInstance();
            System.out.println(o);
            String value = (String) MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue",null);
            System.out.println("Results from getValue: " + value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Following is my second class

```
package com;

public class test1 {

    public String getValue() {
        return "value";
    }

}
```

When i try to run test it gives me the following error

```
    com.test1@1add2dd
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:167)
    at com.test.getName(test.java:18)
    at com.test.main(test.java:9)
```

Please help

Comment: Which version of beanutils are you using?

Comment: Everything seems pretty good. Did you clean and recompile ? Why using reflection to create a new com.test1 ?

Comment: I dont have any decompiler , from eclipse class editor found that beanutils is 1.1 version, but not sure whether it is precise. I got the null pointer exception in my application, so wrote a similar stand alone program.

Comment: @Sridevi Laks: I don't think you are actually running version 1.1 because that particular version did not have a `MethodUtils` class. Perhaps you should try downloading the newest version and use it in your project, just so you know what version you're dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect the short answer is that **you can't provide `null` as the third argument to `MethodUtils.invokeMethod`**.  I'll explain why I suspect this is so (and the [Javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) could really do with mentioning this, if true).

MethodUtils is almost certainly just a layer around the standard Java reflection library.  This takes a method signature, in the form of a name and the classes or the arguments, in order to look up a method.  This is required since one can override a method:

```
public void foo(String s) {
    System.out.println("Got a string: " + s);
}

public void foo(int i) {
    System.out.println("Got an int: " + i);
}
```

So the `invokeMethod` call is bundling a few steps together, but it still needs to be able to look up the right `java.lang.reflect.Method` object.  And in order to do this, it's going to need to know the type of the argument(s) (it looks like the version you're calling is only for unary methods).  So the only way I can see it's able to do this, is to call `arg.getClass()` on the object you pass in - and hey presto, an NPE if you pass in `null`.

---

Edit: I was working with the assumption that you intended to call the `invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object arg)` method - which would indeed exhibit the problems above.  After Adam's comment below, it seems quite possible that you wanted to call the `invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] args)` method which I believe would have worked in this case.

In that case your problem is caused by the compiler's type inference and method signature resolution.  The `null` literal can represent any non-primitive type, so it could work for either `Object` or `Object[]`, while at the same time not representing either of them.  Because of this (and some part of the spec that I'm not 100% sure of) the compiler interprets your `null` as an `Object` and calls that method, with the consequences outlined above.

You could have avoided this if your code contained sufficient information to identify the null as a null array - either by casting:

```
String value = (String) MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue", (Object[])null);
```

or by assigning to a strongly-typed variable:

```
Object[] args = null;
String value = (String) MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue", args);
```

---

Asides from the type inference fixes above, you can work around this problem with `MethodUtils` by supplying the arguments' class information explicitly:

```
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue", new Object[0], new Class[0]);
```

but this would be relatively straightforward, and perhaps even clearer, using standard [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

```
void getName() {
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.test1");
        Object o = c.newInstance();
        System.out.println(o);

        // The next two lines replace the MethodUtils call
        Method getValueMethod = c.getMethod("getValue");
        String value = getValueMethod.invoke(o);

        System.out.println("Results from getValue: " + value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [According to the JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#invokeMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29): "`args` - use these arguments - **treat null as empty array**"

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I could have chosen the wrong, overloaded `invokeMethod` method. What does the Java compiler chose when figuring out if `null` corresponds to an `Object` parameter versus an `Object[]` parameter?

Comment: +1 for making me smile at `hey presto, an NPE if you pass in null`

Comment: @Adam - that's a very good point.  From my reading of [JLS section 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183), I would expect the `Object[]` method to be considered more specific than `Object` and so be called.  But then presumably the type inference for `null` had already happened and decided that it was an `Object`, in which case the other method matched exactly...

Comment: Ah, very insightful , I have used MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue", new Object[0], new Class[0]); it is working fine, thank you, when I get enough reputations to will give you all votes for the help :) Thanks much  Andrzej Doyle

Comment: But casting here did not work                                      String value = (String) MethodUtils.invokeMethod(o, "getValue", (Object[])null);                                                  This still gave the same NPE

Comment: @Sridevi Laks: Congratulations, you have now passed the 15 reputation required to up-vote. :)

Comment: @Sridevi: Maybe you're using a different version of the library to the one I looked at.  In v1.8.3 a `null` array should be converted into an empty array instead - though arguably it's clearer just to pass in the empty array yourself anyway, as you say you're doing above.

Answer (score 0):

why not using

```
String value = (String) MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(o, "getValue",null);
```

is gives no exception with the null third argument